# Is there any header file in c or c++ to implement data structures like graph,trees etc?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, header-files

Is there any header file in c or c++ to implement data structure like graph,trees,stack etc?

Comment: What do you mean by header files? Do you mean you need some 3rd party libs which have implemented these data structures for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean standard library provided data structures which you can just use without actually writing the code for creating the data structures.

Standard c does not provide any such ready to use constructus a few open source libraries do provide the functionality though.

In C++ the standard Library provides for a variety of template based container classes which you might want to use.

Have a look at **[std::stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/)** &
**[Standard Library containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)**

Answer (score 1):

C++ has `<stack>`, and some uses of trees like maps, sets, and heaps.

See Boost.Graph for more C++ graph support.

You have worse support for data structures in C (essentially none in standard C), but you could try GLib.

Comment: The problem of C was of course the lack of generic programming, which is somewhat annoying to create data structure. I believe GLib gets around this by using macros instead, is that right ?

Answer (score 1):

In standard C, no.

In C++, you have `std::stack` for, well, stack. `#include <stack>`

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have STL([Standard Template Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fe2x6kt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) which has vector,queue,maps etc.

You can also use [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) which has much more robust [data structures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/libraries.htm#Containers)